# Reshowing maximized QWidget

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm facing a problem when running Qt applications. Consider the following code snippet.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget mainWindow;
    mainWindow.setMinimumWidth(400);
    mainWindow.setWindowTitle("Main window");
    QVBoxLayout *layout1 = new QVBoxLayout(&mainWindow);
    QPushButton *pushButton = new QPushButton("Click to open aux window");
    layout1->addWidget(pushButton);

    QWidget *auxWindow = new QWidget(&mainWindow, Qt::Window);
    auxWindow->setMinimumWidth(400);
    auxWindow->setWindowTitle("Aux window");
    QVBoxLayout *layout2 = new QVBoxLayout(auxWindow);
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("This is aux window");
    layout2->addWidget(label);

    QObject::connect(pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, auxWindow, &QWidget::show);

    mainWindow.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

This code creates a window (main window) in which there is a push button. This push button, when clicked, shows another window (aux window). If the user had previously closed aux window, pushing main window's push button causes aux window to reopen.

I need aux window to reopen in the maximization state it had before being closed, and it seems Qt does it automatically, so that if the user closes the window maximized, it is reshown maximized.

The problem is aux window is not painted properly when reshown maximized. Aux window is reopened with the correct maximized size, but its contents are displayed as if it had its default unmaximized size.

[image]
<sup>*Aux window maximized before being closed for the first time.*</sup>

[image]
<sup>*Aux window maximized after being closed for the first time and reshown.*</sup>

I know I could use `QWidget::showMaximized()` if I wanted aux window to reopen maximized, but, again, I need aux window to restore its previous maximization state, which is not always maximized.

So, what is the correct way to have a maximized reshown window painted properly?

I'm using Qt 5.9.3 on Windows 10.

Comment: In my case, if I close the maximized auxiliary window does not open maximized, does that code reproduce your problem?

Comment: Yes, it does reproduce my problem. Maybe a Qt 5.9.3 on Windows 10 misbehaviour? I'll try it on other platforms.

Comment: When I close the auxiliary window maximized, and I press the button this auxiliary window opens with its minimum size, I am using Qt 5.10.1 in Linux. Are you using QSettings?

Comment: On Qt5.10 same as @eyllanesc

Comment: Qt 5.9.0 / win10, same, it shows minimized.

Comment: @eyllanesc No, I'm not using QSettings. By yours and @Mohammad Kanan's comments, it seems my Qt installation's got a problem. The window should not be reshown with maximized size. Maybe I shall keep track of the window maximization state before it gets closed and call either `QWidget::showNormal()` or `QWidget::showMaximized()` instead

Comment: I would recommend using QSettings to save the status of your window, and when it is displayed, restore those values.

Comment: Also have a look at Qt documentation `QWidget::shownormal()` , or `QWidget::window->show()`

Comment: @LuisABOL Have you found a workaround for your problem? I'm facing the same issue in PyQt5.

Comment: Here is the workaround I used to fix the issue in my application: https://github.com/jnsebgosselin/qwatson/commit/308d2eb3defdf6bddbce46c60706318f49ae5d7a

Answer (score 2):

It's a Qt bug, and the workaround is to force a relayout of the window via a *delayed* [`QWidget::updateGeometry`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#updateGeometry). The window has the correct state, but the layout doesn't get the message, so to speak.

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  using self = MyWidget;
  using base_class = QWidget;
  //...
protected:
  void showEvent(QShowEvent *ev) override {
    QTimer::singleShot(0, this, [this]{
      qDebug() << geometry();
      updateGeometry();
    });
    base_class::showEvent(ev);
  }
};
```

Comment: That didn't work, unfortunately :( I'll try to test it on a 5.9.5 setup

Comment: @LuisABOL See the edit: how does the geometry output look?

Comment: When I first open aux window, geometry output is QRect(640,287 400x42), which is correct. But when I reopen aux window after having maximized it and closed it, geometry output is QRect(0,29 400x42). The window is maximized, but the content does not fit the window, since geometry's width and height is not being updated

Comment: Does it help if you `setAttribute(Qt::WA_Resized, true)` before calling `updateGeometry()`?

Comment: Also @KubaOber do you have a link to a Qt bug report related to this issue? That would be much appreciated thank you.

Comment: No idea. It is a bug, but whether it got reported or not I don't know.